# Android Catch runtime exceptions on real mobile

Tags: android

I don't know if this question is repeated, just let me know and I will delete this entry.

My problem is simple, I have developed a runtime lib for Android applications that sometimes give me a Toast with a runtime error. This error is not catched and I'm not connected with Logcat (this happens at random times and I don't know how to reproduce this errors).

My question is if there is any utility to save runtime errors on real mobiles into a file so you can check the logcat after to fix that bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out https://www.bugsense.com/

Comment: I will, is this question duplicated?

Comment: I have found catlog also, I will see if this helps also.